# Refreshing booting file without reboot

Tags: boot

Which file would you use, if you had to rotate the HDMI screen without rebooting the system?

Atm. I am using /boot/config.txt, but I can't find any way to refresh this file without rebooting.

Would it be possible to use another file, which have the permissions to rotate the screen and also have the ability to be refreshed without having to reboot the system?

Comment: Is this referencing a Raspberry Pi? If so, it seems that it cannot be done: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=64&t=44007

Comment: Dayum, sorry for my lame posting here.. Maybe I should start using raspberrypi.org.. Thanks for fast response...